# why date-time is automatically changed to the object datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, excel-automation

Need to convert object type to Date-time and use that converted date-time is unknowingly changed to the object again while filtering.

```
msft['Tested On'] = pd.to_datetime(msft['Tested On'])
msft['Tested On'].dt.date
df = msft[msft['Tested On'] == '2018-02-02']
```

Actual result: 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Expected result:
Need to display the filtered list with the other rows and columns also

Comment: Do you assign `msft['Tested On'].dt.date` ? Can you add some data sample?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568016/how-to-filter-the-date-in-excel-using-pandas) Data in that link-page will help

Comment: I don't how add a table in stack overflow, that's why created a link.

Comment: @gomathisubramanian you can just attach `df_to_dict()` so people can reproduce your example quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and if first digit is day, add parameter `dayfirst=True`:

```
print (msft)
  Title plan     run   status           Tested On
0     A   P0      P0   Passed  11/08/2018 8:42 AM
1     B   P0      P0   Failed  12/08/2018 8:42 AM
2     C    -  Canary   Passed  10/08/2018 8:42 AM
3     D    -  Sanity  Blocked  11/08/2018 8:42 AM

msft['Tested On'] = pd.to_datetime(msft['Tested On'], dayfirst=True)
print (msft)
  Title plan     run   status           Tested On
0     A   P0      P0   Passed 2018-08-11 08:42:00
1     B   P0      P0   Failed 2018-08-12 08:42:00
2     C    -  Canary   Passed 2018-08-10 08:42:00
3     D    -  Sanity  Blocked 2018-08-11 08:42:00
```

Then remove times by [`dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and compare:

```
df = msft[msft['Tested On'].dt.floor('d') == '2018-08-11']
print (df)
  Title plan     run   status           Tested On
0     A   P0      P0   Passed 2018-08-11 08:42:00
3     D    -  Sanity  Blocked 2018-08-11 08:42:00
```

**Detail**:

```
print (msft['Tested On'].dt.floor('d'))
0   2018-08-11
1   2018-08-12
2   2018-08-10
3   2018-08-11
Name: Tested On, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: But when i i tried this with my code, i get an Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Plan, Run, Status, Tested On]
Index: []

Comment: With your real data?

Comment: Ah now I get the Datetime type. but the result is getting the empty dataframe

Comment: Can you check if data re converted to datetimes correctly? If not swapped day with months?

Comment: `print (msft['Tested On'].dt.floor('d'))` - why d is for?

Comment: it is day, it remove times